# Trouble locating button element by id or xpath with Selenium (python). Element appears to have multiple ID names

Tags: python, selenium

I've been trying to locate a button by ID, xpath, link text and partial link text but get the "unable to locate element" error every time.

The element's html is as follows:

```
<a href="https://s1.ebridge.com/ebridge/3.0/retrieve/search.aspx?search=new&amp;guid=14f2de4c-b37a-4632-a593-48d8aa12b468" id="aView" onclick="clickme(this,'retrieve')" target="main">Retrieve</a>
```

The page it's on is behind a login screen which I can get through without any issues. Here's my code from start to the error:

```
>>> from selenium import webdriver
>>> from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>> import re
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> import os
>>> url = "https://s1.ebridge.com/ebridge/3.0/default.aspx?1"
>>> driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path="/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/11/bin/geckodriver")
>>> driver.implicitly_wait(30)
>>> driver.get(url)
>>> username = driver.find_element_by_name("tbUserName")
>>> username.clear()
>>> username.send_keys("public")
>>> password = driver.find_element_by_name("tbPassword")
>>> password.clear()
>>> password.send_keys("public")
>>> file_cabinet = driver.find_element_by_name("tbFileCabinet")
>>> file_cabinet.clear()
>>> file_cabinet.send_keys("PINCHD")
>>> file_cabinet.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
>>> driver.implicitly_wait(30)
>>> retrieve = driver.find_element_by_id("retrieve").click()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 360, in find_element_by_id
return self.find_element(by=By.ID, value=id_)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 978, in find_element
'value': value})['value']
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable to locate element: [id="retrieve"]
```

It looks like the element has two different ID's, both of which I've tried without success (i.e. 'retrieve' and 'aView').

I've also tried searching by partial link text ('Retrieve') and by xpath (//*[@id="aView"]) without success.

Any advice is appreciated.

[page behind login page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2YAXu.png)

[element circled in red, arrow pointing to html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8vIK3.png)

Answer (score 0):

You are using wrong ID for button. It has "btnLogin" id. Use that id to find your login button.

Attaching the screenshot for your reference.[image]

Comment: Ahh, I accidentally omitted part of my original code: ">>> file_cabinet.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)" comes after the line that mentions "PINCHD". So I don't have to click the button you're talking about. The button I'm having trouble with comes on the next page that loads after the RETURN command.